# Mac OS Mojave freezing after wake from sleep: i recently updated my system

Tags: macos, mac, mojave

after upgrade to Mac OS Mojave in my MacBookPro 2016 and my iMac they froze after wake if they're sleeping.

This happen if the Mac sleep for a while, overnight for example, and delays a few seconds to unfreeze and be possible to operate.

During this freezing time, the spinning colored ball stay frozen in the screen, and is not possible to anything until it unfreeze.

Can you suggest some solution...